# How do I know if I need a visa for travel to Spain for a conference as a US citizen?

Tags: visas, spain

I'm a U.S. citizen and resident. I'm going to be attending a conference in Spain in September. I started to fill out the registration form, and one of the questions is, "Do you require a visa letter?"

How do I know if I require a visa letter? The conference is work-related, but hosted by a non-Spanish company, and I won't be making any money off the trip.

ETA: if it makes a difference, I'll only be there for a week.

Comment: You don't need a visa

Comment: Are you only attending the conference, not being paid for speaking there? (Not sure it makes a difference for the Schengen Area but it did make a big difference for the UK)

Comment: Only attending, but apparently it doesn't make a difference, as per the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to visit a Schengen country such as Spain for tourism or business for less than 90 days without a visa.

From the [US Department of State Bureau of Consular Affairs](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Spain.html):

> Spain is a party to the Schengen Agreement. This means that U.S. citizens may enter Spain for up to 90 days for tourist or business purposes without a visa. Your passport should be valid for at least three months beyond the period of stay.  You need sufficient funds and a return airline ticket. For additional details about travel into and within Schengen countries, please see our Schengen fact sheet. Visit the Embassy of Spain website for the most current visa information.

Comment: Thank you! The last time I was out of the country was in 1996, when I was just out of college, and all of our paperwork was taken care of by the group I was traveling with.

Answer (score 0):

Citizens of the United States are not required to have visas to enter any of the countries of the European Union. The Schengen area is a large part of the European Union.